# Como saber si un archivo existe en Google Cloud en app-engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

quiero ver si es posible con lo que tengo a la mano:

```
String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
                String bucket = request.getParameter("bucket");

                BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket, filename);
                Blob es = storage.get(blobId);

                if (es != null) {
                    jsonResponse.put("existe", es.exists());
                    jsonResponse.put("size", es.getSize());
                    jsonResponse.put("kb", es.getSize() / 1024);
                } else {
                    jsonResponse.put("existe", false);
                    jsonResponse.put("size", 0);
                    jsonResponse.put("kb", 0);
                }
                out.println(jsonResponse);
```

El tema esta en que si existe me tira true en algunas ocasiones y en otras no retorna nada y si el bucket esta mal truena, cosa que esta bien, lo raro es que si el bucket y lo demas esta bien, deberia regresar un false si no existe, pero solo regresa null.

Al principio pense que se debia a la forma en que se estructuro el BlobId, pero cuando retorna true esta bien todo.

*Ya intente preguntando es.exists() dentro del if, pero no funciona como esperaba, cuando no lo encuentra tira vacio.
Podria preguntar si es diferente de null y si existe, pero ahi esta el tema, que es lo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver tus archivos en app engine vas a versiones de hay a la penúltima linea le das en herramientas => origen y te habré todo el proyecto que has deployado y ves tus archivos subidos, según tu código probablemente este mal el ruteo de tu index o app.yaml